# How to reverse a list without using reverse() and without using return

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I need a code that reverses a list without using both return of reverse(). So it can only modify the inputted list. These are the methods i have tried so far that havent worked:

```
def reversed(x):
    x[::-1]
```

and

```
def reverse(x):
    in_list = [] 
for i in range(1, len(x)+1): 
    x.append(x[-i])
```

The second code gives me an error of 'name 'x' is not defined'

Comment: Watch your indentation on your second function

Comment: You need a code? Do you mean a function? Or a statement? And do you mean you can't use the builtin `reversed` function or `return` statement?

Comment: Do you want a list expression like [x[-(i+1)] for i in range(len(x))]

Comment: You probably want to run the `for` loop inside the `reverse(x)` function. So, you need to indent the `for` loop appropriately.

Comment: Why can't you use `return`?  `reversed = lambda x: x[::-1]`.

Comment: I cant use the built in reverse function or the return statement

Comment: Is this for a homework assignment? Seems like one of very few places such a constraint would be placed

Answer (score 1):

You could assign x to it's reversed value:

```
x = x[::-1]
```

This is the same as your first example although it reassigns the variable.

Comment: You have to use a slice assignment (`x[:] = x[::-1]`), otherwise you are just rebinding the local name `x` without affecting the list it originally referred to.

Comment: Although in either situation won't `x` be assigned to the same value after either approach @chepner? Isn't that the intended result? I could be wrong

Comment: Actually I see what you're saying although OP isn't very clear on what they want really. I assumed `x` would be the only variable at hand.

Comment: Oh, I was assuming you were supplying the body of the OP's `reverse` function. If it's the same scope, yes, this is fine.

Comment: No this is just an inline statement

Answer (score 0):

```
def reverse_list(x):
    return x[::-1]

x =[1,2,3,4,5]
 
y = reverse_list(x)

print(y)
```

Output: [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]

Answer (score 0):

First, *don't do this*. Mutating data structures makes your coworkers hate you. But if you must, consider:

```
def mutate(lst):
    backward = lst[::-1]
    lst.clear()
    lst.extend(backward)

a = [1,2,3,4]
print(a)
print(id(a))

mutate(a)
print(a)
print(id(a))
```

The `mutate` function makes a reversed copy of its inputs. Then it clears the contents of the list that was passed in so that it's empty. Finally, it fills that empty list with the reversed copy. This way the original object is mutated in place and retains its original ID.

Alternatively, if you're extremely resource limited and are willing for the code to be slower in exchange for not having to temporarily duplicate the input list, you could swap the first and last items, then the second and second-to-lsat items, and so on until you reach the middle of the list:

```
def mutate_by_swapping(lst):
    last_index = len(lst) - 1
    for i in range(len(lst) // 2):
        lst[i], lst[last_index - i] = lst[last_index - i], lst[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x = ["a", "b", "c", "d","e"]

z = []

for i in range(len(x)):
    m = len(x) - i -1
    z.insert(i,x[m])

print(z)
```

**Output will be:** `['e', 'd', 'c', 'b', 'a']`